# MacBook Pro screen is strange, but not with external screen

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen

[image]

My sons MacBook Pro 13" Retina (Early 2015) has a problem with the built-in screen. It will very shortly look OK, followed by what to me looks like a HW  issue, with strange patterns and lines.

But the odd thing is that whenever I plug in the HDMI, to an external screen - both the built-in, and the external screens look fine.

Sometimes I can also run the machine without the problem happening. I have tried to work the hinge on the screen, but there is no flicker or any reaction.

Is this still a HW issue, or could it be something else?

Comment: I'd bet hardware. If it goes away after a while something has reached a critical temperature, and starts to work. If the external monitor is fine then it is likely something in the display itself rather than the video card, depending on how your Mac is internally configured with video cards.

Comment: There's one sure way to see if it's hardware or not - take a screen shot.  If the image is good, you have a hardware issue.

Comment: @Allan - the screenshot looks fine. :-(

Comment: I was afraid of that...it's hardware.

Comment: I answered a very similar question (your display is actually worse) so I'm going to tag it as a dupe since the resolution is exactly the same - take it in for service.  And...I feel your pain...it really sucks to be in this spot where the display has failed *physically*.  I wish there was better news to give you.